# A custom route along with resource routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

I have setup a custom route, and it seems to work. However, I also have a resources routes as well for the same controller. I think I am just doing something wrong, but I can't tell what it is. I am honestly hacking together routes since I am still a bit confused on how to set them up and when to use what method.

Here are my routes I am dealing with right now.

```
resources :shows
match "shows/:country" => "shows#index"
```

The routes like the are the resources :shows works just fine, but not the match. If I flip them the match route works fine, but the resources :shows doesn't.

Should I do this as a namespaced route? I am not exactly sure what I should do. What I am trying to accomplish is something like this.

```
http://site.com/shows/canada
```

That will return all Candian shows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want to do is use [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints), or maybe even a [custom constraints class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints). Here's a rough start that I haven't tested and am unsure if it would work:

```
resources :shows, :constraints => { :id => /[0-9]+/ }
match "shows/:country" => "shows#index", :constraints => { :country => /[a-z]+/ }
```

Note that typically this would be done via a get query parameter, e.g. `http://example.com/shows?country=canada`, which would already go to your `shows#index` action and have `params[:country]` set to `"canada"`.

Comment: Yeah I understand normally should do it via querystring, but I have a need for doing it this way. The code kind of works it breaks the edit_show_path helper, but not the new_show_path. Is that because of the :id constraint of the resources shows line?

Comment: Does manually visiting an edit path work (e.g. `/edit/1`)? Or is it just the path generation helper that's broken?

Comment: Sorry I'm unsure of how to go about solving that, mixing and matching RESTful and non-RESTful routes isn't really the convention so it's not entirely surprising that the path helpers are confused. It's not the best, but you can fallback on `url_for`. You may also wish to run `rake routes` to see how Rails is actually interpreting your routes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep messing with it to see if I can't figure it out some how. If I need to I guess I could always do it with query strings and just setup a custom .htaccess file.

Comment: This is the solution I just had bad code in other places. I also had some bad routing tests as well. Need to work on writing better tests, too. This was a mix of bad view code and bad tests. When I stripped all that away and went at it fresh everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting bitten by the default route which expects `/{controller}/{action}` and routes accordingly.  Try removing the default route.  You will have to make sure to declare all of your routes, but the result is a more predictable set of routes for your app.

Comment: I was thinking about taking this approach, but would like to avoid it if I can.